# VBA Class() object as property of another class

Tags: excel, class, vba

I'm trying to create a class to hold a variable number of items (which are themselves another class object).

So, I have Class 2:

```
' Class 2 contain each individual quote elements (OTC and MRC)

Private pOTC As String
Private pMRC As String
Public Property Get OTC() As String
    OTC = pOTC
End Property
Public Property Let OTC(Value As String)
    pOTC = Value
End Property

Public Property Get MRC() As String
    MRC = pMRC
End Property
Public Property Let MRC(Value As String)
    pMRC = Value
End Property
```

Then Class 1 contains an array of Class 2:

```
Private pCurr As String
Private pQuote(20) As Class2

Public Property Get Curr() As String
    Curr = pCurr
End Property
Public Property Let Curr(Value As String)
    pCurr = Value
End Property

Public Property Set Quote(Index As Integer, cQuote As Class2)
    Set pQuote(Index) = cQuote
End Property

Public Property Get Quote(Index As Integer) As Class2
    Quote = pQuote(Index)
End Property
```

And what I would like to do is something like:

```
Dim myQuotes As Class1
Set myQuotes = New Class1

myQuotes.Curr = "GBP"
myQuotes.Quote(3).OTC = "1200"
```

The first line setting myQuotes.Curr is no problem, however when I try to set a value inside the array the next line errors with ***Run-time 91 Object variable or With block variable not set***

Any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong and how can I set the values for the elements within the class array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: besides the solution to your problem which is below thanks to Alex K., can I just ask (of curiosity) why are you doing it the way you are instead of using a collection of quotes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you `myQuotes.Quote(3)` you call `Property Get Quote` which has an issue.

Your internal array of `Class2` is not instantiated so `pQuote(Index)` refers to an array element of `Nothing`, when you then `myQuotes.Quote(3).OTC =` you try to assign to `Nothing` which fails.

You need to make sure `pQuote(Index)` is instanced; you can do this on demand:

```
Public Property Get Quote(Index As Integer) As Class2
   If (pQuote(Index) Is Nothing) Then Set pQuote(Index) = New Class2
   Set Quote = pQuote(Index)
End Property
```

(Note the required `Set`)

Or by adding an intitialisation routine to `Class1`:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim Index As Long
    For Index = 0 To UBound(pQuote)
         Set pQuote(Index) = New Class2
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked!! I also found another mistake in Class1, as it should read **Set Quote = pQuote(Index)**: `Public Property Get Quote(Index As Integer) As Class2
    Set Quote = pQuote(Index)
End Property `

Answer (score 2):

You need to set them as New Class2 in Class1:

```
For intI = LBOUND(pQuote) to UBOUND(pQuote)
    Set pQuote(intI) =  New Class2
Next IntI
```

Just as you do with **Class1** in your final script.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should be

```
Public Property Let Quote(Index As Integer, cQuote As Class2)
    Set pQuote(Index) = cQuote
End Property
```